# Accordion JS. How add class on click to other class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, accordion

How can I add .active to .accordion-item when I click to .accordion-item-header?
I want to add .active to switch my bgc with javascript without jquery.

HTML

```
                    <div class="accordion">
                        <div class="accordion-item">
                            <div class="accordion-item-header">Basics</div>
                            <div class="accordion-item-body">
                                <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
                                    Lorem Ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-item">
                            <div class="accordion-item-header">Standard</div>
                            <div class="accordion-item-body">
                                <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
                                    Lorem Ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-item">
                            <div class="accordion-item-header">Pro care</div>
                            <div class="accordion-item-body">
                                <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
                                    Lorem Ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS (SCSS)

```
.accordion {
    border: 1px solid #E3E1D5;
    border-radius: 20px;  
    padding: 40px 40px 30px 40px;    
    height: 100%;
    &-item {
        width: 250px;
        padding: 14px 40px;
        background: #EDF2EC;
        border-radius: 20px;
        &:not(:first-child) {
            margin-top: 32px;
        }
        // &.active {
        //     background: #D6E7D2;
        // }
        &-header {
            position: relative;
            font-family: 'Inter';
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #000000;
            cursor: pointer;
            &::after {
                content: url('../icons/arrows/prices_arrow.svg');
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                transition: all 0.6s;
            }
            &.active {
                &::after {
                    content: url('../icons/arrows/prices_arrow.svg');
                    transform: rotate(-180deg);
                }
            }
        } 
        &-body {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: all 0.6s;
            &.active {
                max-height: 400px;
            }
            &-content {
                margin-top: 12px;
                border-top: 0.5px solid #AEA1A1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JS

```
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item-header').forEach((accordionItemHeader) => {  //получаю все header на которые буду нажимать
    accordionItemHeader.addEventListener('click', () => {
        accordionItemHeader.classList.toggle('active'); //добавляю класс активности для header + <-> -
        const accordionItemBody = accordionItemHeader.nextElementSibling; //получаю следующий элемент за header
        if(accordionItemHeader.classList.contains('active')) {    
            //если у header есть класс активности, тогда выставляем max-height
            accordionItemBody.style.maxHeight = accordionItemBody.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
        else {
            accordionItemBody.style.maxHeight = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Ds6.png)
I want to add this class to accordion-item when I click on accordion-item-header.
I do not know, how I can get accordion-item. I tried querySelector and in this case I change bgc only on first class even when I click on the second or third element, the bgc changes only for the first.
I tried to use querySelectorAll but in this case I change my bgc for all element even the ones I didn't click on.

```
        &.active {
            background: #D6E7D2;
        }
```

Comment: Just to note, querySelectorAll returns a nodelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item-header').forEach((accordionItemHeader) => {  //получаю все header на которые буду нажимать
        accordionItemHeader.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
            console.log(evt.target);
            const elai = evt.target.closest('.accordion-item');
            console.log(elai);
            elai.classList.toggle('active'); //добавляю класс активности для header + <-> -
        });
    });
```

in your eventlistener just add 'event' (evt)

from this evt.target element clicked, you search 'closest' accordion-item

and you toggle your class